# system identification: MATLAB tfestimate gives different results for different Fs

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, frequency-response, control-systems, system-identification

So I have an experimental data; A is a chirp signal (sweep sine wave) and B is the response of the system. I identify the system as follows in MATLAB:

```
figure
Ts= 1e-4;
Fs = 1/Ts;
[T,f]=tfestimate(A,B,[],[],[],Fs);
semilogx(f,20*log10(abs(T)));
grid
```

But when I change Ts to different values (e.g. 1e-2), the plot changes. For instance
[image: This is with Ts = 1e-2]

This is with Ts = 1e-2

[image: This is with Ts = 1e-4]

This is with Ts = 1e-4

Can anyone help me figure out what the correct value of Ts is, so my reported eigenfrequencies are correct?

Comment: why not use the actual sample rate?

Comment: Please also respond to the comments on the same question you posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ControlTheory/comments/a9y948/matlab_tfestimate_gives_different_results_for) instead of reposting the question at multiple places.

Comment: what is your B ?